# How to make a block visible only to one page

Tags: blocks

I have made a custom block and i want to make it visible only to pages that follow this pattern: user/[user-id]/galleries.

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are Visibility settings for blocks in Drupal. One of options is "Show block on specific pages". Select "Only the listed pages" and input `user/*/galleries`

Comment: Good point. No need to use PHP.

Answer (score 1):

In the *Page specific visibility settings*, select *Show if the following PHP code returns TRUE (PHP-mode, experts only)* and enter

```
return arg(0) === 'user'
    && is_numeric(arg(1))
    && arg(2) === 'galleries'
    && arg(3) === null;
```

in the *Pages* text input field. Skip the `&& arg(3) === null` part if you also want to display the block on pages further down in the hierarchy (e.g. on `user/[user-id]/galleries/private`).

Comment: Although not the best answer for *this* situation, this is actually a very good tip. Thanks friend!